# What is the past tense of "lightning"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-tense

When we talk about lightning and thunder, we generally use the words like this:

1. It's lightning
2. It's thundering
3. The antenna was hit by lightning

But sometimes we use thunder in the past tense...

1. It thundered twice before lightning hit the tower.
2. It rained heavily yesterday and thundered so severely.

Now, how do we use the word lightning in the past tense like the word thunder? Does the verb 'lightning' have a past tense?

Comment: How could you check?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth my Oxford doesn't have it. Perhaps someone has access to a larger dictionary or lexicon.

Comment: Dictionary.com has *lightninged*. Not sure how far to trust it. However, the word is almost never used. Also, since *lightning* comes from *lightening*, the "proper" past would be *lightened*, but that is certainly an obsolete usage.

Comment: yes, many sources don't even list "lightning" as a verb, and I never ever hear that, nor have heard it. Interesting though that the example you provide in present progressive is "It's lightning," which could, I suppose, not be a present progressive at all but rather answer the question "What is it?" But you're asking about the verb, and when you say "we generally say", I'm assuming the "generally" refers in some way to frequency; and though I may misunderstand what you mean by "we", but if that includes me, then I'd have to say you're wrong: we don't generally say "It's lightning."

Comment: Related: *[What is the correct present continuous form of “thunder” and “lightning”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85207)*

Comment: Correct? Perhaps: "is lightninging," but really, the market will not (does not, according to concordances and Google Ngram) bear it.

Comment: You have access to what are almost certainly larger dictionaries. At TheFreeDictionary, both AHDEL and RHKWebster's list the -ed form as 'lightninged' and an invariant -ing form. guifa confirms that OED also licenses these verb forms. The fact that Collins does not list them indicates that their use may be rare, especially in the UK. Roaring Fish suggests a less strange-sounding (to my British ears) alternative to 'lightninged' in 'lightened' (though some would argue that's not what you asked for).

Comment: @Amadan Frequency of use, not etymology, is taken as the standard of acceptability ('properness').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree, which was the reason for the scare quotes. However, I was not too off the mark, as the disparity between the answers rather clearly shows.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth probably the best universal solution is to use "There was lightning", because I'd imagine most people in my area would misunderstand "last night it lightened" as perhaps missing the word "up" and refering to the wind or rain not being as intense.

Comment: "There was lightning and it thundered." If you see a verb form of *lightning* in use (*lightninging, lightninged* ), 1. suspect if it is a gerund (noun) per context 2. Else accept it for its contextual meaning. However, always avoid using the word as a noun. This I believe is the idea behind current editions of some standard dictionaries **not** including *lightning* as a verb (any more).

Comment: @guifa Universal solutions in English!? We'd have nothing to argue about. I mean discuss. Over here, the PP version 'It was thundering and lightning last night' is quite often used, as is the gerund (though 'lightning' is probably deverbal here) version 'There was thundering and lightning'. The coupling disambiguates; 'It was lightning' (PP version) is very rare, though 'Was that lightning?' is used. One just has to be aware of local (-lish) practice. When in the US, walk on the sidewalk (and drive on the right).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth haha, true.  I more meant, since no one contests or would confuse the noun *lightning* on either side of the pond, I should have called it the "least  potentially ambiguous and/or contestable" form ;)

Comment: We seem to use Lightninging and lightninged, but the pronunciation is a bit odd - light nee ying?! and light nind. The "t" is nearly not there.

Answer (score 13):

OED lists *lightning* as a verb and includes the past tense form *lightninged*:

> **Lightning**, *v.*: = lighten *v.<sup>2</sup> 6.* Also *fig*
>
> 1903   Westm. Gaz. 16 Nov. 8/2   The two metal balls..thundered and **lightninged** as they delivered the message.
>
> 1926   H. Caine in Strand Mag. Jan. 20/1   Mr. Gladstone leapt to his feet, whereupon the air of the House thundered and **lightninged** for a short ten minutes.
>
> 1935   Z. N. Hurston Mules & Men i. i. 27   You know, when it **lightnings**, de angels is peepin' in de lookin' glass.

This is not some mere quotation from the entry of *lighten*, as you can see, it's listed explicitly as a separate entry, separate from the noun form, with a single sense.  Here's it's **entry** profile:
[image]

Contrary to people saying this is not a common form or inadvisable, I'm a native speaker, I use it, and can confirm that everyone around me (I'm in the US South) uses it.  To me, *lightened* only has an inchoative meaning (that is, *to become lighter*) and I would never use it to refer to the electrical discharge and likely not understand it as such barring other context clues.  Notice that the original citations are from England (although Edwin says it's unused in Britain these days), and the OED doesn't list it as being obsolete, literary, dialectal, rare.  Curiously, for most (myself included), the present participle is invariable, although given that Urban Dictionary has [several](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Lightninging) entries for it, it's possible someone uses it somewhere.  Personally, if I did, since I normally pronounce *-ing* as [n̩], there'd be little perceptible difference between [lɑ̝ʔ.nə̆n] and [lɑ̝ʔ.nə̆n.n̩].

While I admit it may be more frequent in my dialect, it's certainly used in higher, academic registers.  For example, looking at the linguistics article "What Rains?" (Bill J. Darden, *Linguistic Inquiry* 4.4 [1973]), the verb is used in line with other verbs in a linguistics article about a completely different topic:

> Even in English there are problems that for the presumption that every sentence has a subject.  In sentences such as (1), the *it* seems to have neither of the normal functions of pronouns:
>   (1) It rained (snowed, thundered, **lightninged**).
>   It is not deitic, nor does it refer to an entity named by another noun phrase.

Likewise, in another article, "Grammar and Existence: A Preface to Ontology" (from *Mind*, 1960, Oxford UP) we can find:

> *That* it has just **lightninged** (causally) implies *that* it will shortly thunder. (p. 519)

In fact, you can even find a compounded past participle form of it in Judith Witt's review of two books in *Modern Philology* 90.2 (1992):

> “A kiss is just a kiss, even when it is a great kiss,” cautions Susan Morgan of the **white-lightninged** climax of James's *Portrait of a Lady* (1881).  (p. 285)

Even more recently, it was used in "June Twelfth" (Anatoly Naiman, *American Poetry Review* 34.4 [2005]:

> Yesterday was sunny and warm, then a storm struck,
>   It thundered and **lightninged**, it poured, and then the sun came out again. (p. 39)

And also a figurative use from 1992 ("Gardening, The Professor", Jill P. Baumgaertner, *The Centennial Review* 36.3 [1992])

> … These lumpy legs / he hangs from trellises next to the pond / **lightninged** with the fish

And a present simple usage since people still don't think the verb exists separately, from "Naturalism and Process" (Hegeler Institute, *The Monist* 64.1 [1981]):

> 48. We now need to note the existence in the manifest framework of verbs which take dummy subjects.
>
>     - It rains
>     - It thunders
>     - It **lightnings** (p. 47)

---

According to [Google N-Grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thundered%20and%20lightninged%20%2B%20thunders%20and%20lightnings%2Cthundered%20and%20lightened%2Bthunders%20and%20lightens&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28thundered%20and%20lightninged%20%2B%20thunders%20and%20lightnings%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28thundered%20and%20lightened%20%2B%20thunders%20and%20lightens%29%3B%2Cc0), lightning is the prefered verb in the phrase *thunder and [lighten|lightning]*, though both clearly exist and are used.

Given that others seem to refute the existance of *lightning[s|ed]* as a verb even in spite of the clear evidence to the contrary, if you wish to use a past tense construction, your best bet is going to be to say that *there was lightning* avoiding the verbs entirely or use *it was lightning* which (I think) is acceptable spelling on both sides of the Atlantic. Besides, these days, it seems for the past few decades, most people use the "there was lightning" structure [a lot more](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+was+thunder+and+lightning%2Cit+thundered+and+lightninged%2Bit+thundered+and+lightened%2Bit+was+thundering+and+lightning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20was%20thunder%20and%20lightning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28it%20thundered%20and%20lightninged%20%2B%20it%20thundered%20and%20lightened%20%2B%20it%20was%20thundering%20and%20lightning%29%3B%2Cc0) than any other form *combined*.

Comment: Shouldn't one contrast the results for 'thundered and lightninged'/'thundered and lightened'? {[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thundered+and+lightninged%2Cthundered+and+lightened&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthundered%20and%20lightninged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthundered%20and%20lightened%3B%2Cc0)} This shows the latter as 5x as common as the former. Even this really surprises me; obviously I'm being too parochial. My apologies to the the South. _Only_ the latter seems to be used here in the UK; the other flatlines.

Comment: Presumably, for most people *lightning* is either an irregular verb or a defective verb. Putting it more simply, I don't imagine very many people would say *"lightninging"*.

Comment: Your ngram isn't objective. The question is not about the nouns. By adding "thunders and lightnings" you distort the outcome. Well, never trust a statistic you didn't make yourself.

Comment: @Em1 Those are both generally uncountable in modern English. Plural forms in that ngram ought to be negligible. In any case, it should be clear that lightning is a legitimately used verb, with lightninged as its past tense.

Comment: @guifa ~ I just checked the OED. It has no entry for *lightning* as a verb, and does not list *lightninged* as a past form. Here is the link proving it: -> http://ezproxy.bcu.ac.uk:2333/search?searchType=dictionary&q=lightening&_searchBtn=Search    Whatever dictionary you are using, it is not the OED.

Comment: @RoaringFish http://www.oed.com.proxy.lib.utc.edu/view/Entry/108233?rskey=VkPwST&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid is the URL I'm using

Comment: Stay alert while considering evidence like this, though provided helpfully by standard sources. "You know, when it lightnings, **de** angels **is** peepin' in **de** lookin' glass." is **not** English.

Comment: @Kris It's dialect, for sure, but it's still English.  But that's why the citations that I found (Zora Neal Hurston was quoted by the OED, not me) came from academic journals.  See citations from 1960 and 1992.

Comment: @guifa.. the URL is not the issue - I have the same quotes in my own answer. The problem is your inability to distinguish quotes from an entry. Waving *quotes* from the OED, and declaring that the OED 'lists lightning as a verb with lightninged as the past tense' is misleading to the point of dishonesty.

Comment: @RoaringFish so... the fact that the OED would list *lightning* twice, once under a noun heading and once under a verb heading means nothing?  You're either being willfully ignorant or intentionally obtuse at this point, besides ignoring the ample evidence I've provided of actual real-world use of *lightning* as a verb unto itself with past tense, past participle, and present simple usages.  If you search for "lightning", you will receive two headwords, one as a noun, and one as a verb, again as I'll have documented in my update.

Comment: @guifa ~ you don't seem to know what 'list' means. Look at the entry for lightning as a noun as I have posted already. You get etymology, history, several meanings, slang use, compounds, etc. *That* is an entry. Now look at your alleged 'entry' for lightning as a verb - no history, no meanings, no other usage, no compounds, no information, nothing. Just two examples of use in the early 20th century and a link to the noun entry. That is because what you are looking at is not an entry. It is a simple example of usage, and saying otherwise is misleading.

Comment: @RoaringFish It has an etymology (formed from *lightning, n.*) and it has a definition (synonym of *lighten* in its second verbal entry, 6th definition).  But to be clear, you then consider *lightningy* to not be a word, "just usage" because it too has a sparse entry?

Comment: @guifa ~ It doesn't have an etymology - it links back to the *entry*. The *entry* lemma is the noun *lightning*. What you are calling a 'definition' though we can all see that there is none, is a link back to the *entry* for the verb form lemma *lighten*. It is just example quotes, with links to the relevant entries where you can find etymology and meanings.

Comment: @RoaringFish Right, so I'm just imagining where it says "ETYMOLOGY" and showing it as derived from the *noun* form not the verb *lighten*?  What it is linking back to in the definition is a specific definition with *lighten* and stating that it is synonymous (hence the = sign), and in addition, stating that it can be used figuratively.  But in any case, you are still ignoring the ample number of quotes from academic journals where it is used.  If it didn't exist, and only had, as you say, two quotes in the past 100 years, pray tell, where did I find these quotes from?

Comment: *Lighten* is a verb, listed in the OED. *Lightening* is a verbal noun (gerund if you wish) formed by adding -ing and listed as a noun in the OED as *lightening* and *lightning*. You are saying is that *lightning* is a verb, the OED not only forgot to list with its own entry but mistakenly listed it as a noun, twice, and that this verb - incredibly - has no -ing form! You prop this nonsense up with 6 examples from the past hundred years and pretend that is common usage. I have one single link with 11 examples of *lightened*. If I get 6 examples of 'goed', will you insist that 'went' is wrong?

Comment: Whatever.  I can reach no other conclusion other than that you are being completely and willfully ignorant to the facts.  I have never once stated that *lightened* is an invalid usage, only that it is the past tense of *lighten*, not *lightning* which is a separate verb and at this point I've presented every single piece of evidence to the contrary and you continue to ignore it.  The OED lists *lightning* (sans *e*) under *one* entry as a *noun*, and under a *separate* entry *as a verb*.  Or are you so blind as to not see the little *v.* after the entry on my screenshots?

Comment: @RoaringFish Just because **you** don't use a form doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  Sometimes variations exist in a language.  You cite Dictionary.com, yet apparently conveniently ignore the fact that it too includes *lightning* as a verb, with *lightninged* as its past tense with *lightning* as its invariable present participle.  Good Lord Almighty, how obtuse can you be?  How much more evidence do you need?  I accept that people say *lightened* even though I frankly had never heard it (or at least noticed it) until today.  Why do you refuse to do the same with *lightninged*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18473/discussion-between-guifa-and-roaring-fish).

Answer (score 4):

The word you are looking for is *lightened*.

["It thundered and lightened for hours" from Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lightened)

[Eleven more examples of *lightened* in use](http://nyanglish.com/thundered-and-lightened)

Some individual examples:

[Before it thundered and lightened, or ever the foundations of paradise were 
laid](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/2-Esdras-6-2/)

[On the 11th of April, 1824, it thundered and lightened considerably](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OycA3b_tTE0C&pg=PA353&lpg=PA353&dq=%22thundered%20and%20lightened%22&source=bl&ots=jFkCD4KI0g&sig=K5FWnPvL-tWx94nwKCaAkNn8ZGg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5VNbVPyBItafugTpt4CAAg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22thundered%20and%20lightened%22&f=false)

[In the night of Wednesday, Dec 4, it thundered and lightened very much. We have had wet weather ever since and last night from eleven to one in the morning it thundered and lightened again with great violence](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gvURAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA636&lpg=PA636&dq=%22thundered%20and%20lightened%22&source=bl&ots=-kdj4JqWEE&sig=t1JclmPGBxbVH0YkhEoCR8j1JLs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5VNbVPyBItafugTpt4CAAg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22thundered%20and%20lightened%22&f=false)

More modern examples:

[@ooGloryoo me too! it thundered and lightened and poured here all night](https://mobile.twitter.com/lesl1eanne/statuses/501912684057866242)

[Barely half an hour later it thundered and lightened!](https://m.flickr.com/#/photos/manuel_720921/9719983179/in/favorites-axpazos/)

Turning to Ngram, [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thundered+and+lightened%2Cthundered+and+lightninged&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthundered%20and%20lightened%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthundered%20and%20lightninged%3B%2Cc0) is for *thundered and lightened* versus *thundered and lightninged*, and it says that *thundered and lightninged* is not found. [This one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lightninged&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clightninged%3B%2Cc0) is for *lightninged* on its own, and it is also 'nothing found' This suggests that whatever dictionaries say, the word *lightninged* is not in widespread use.

The reason for this lies in the etymology. The easy-access one is [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lightning&searchmode=none) where we find that *lightning* is not a verb as some are insisting, but is actually a verbal noun formed by adding the -ing suffix to *lighten*.

The paid access one is the good old OED that has more information. Here, we find that *lightning* is still listed as a noun and not a verb:

*lightning, n.*

*Pronunciation:  /ˈlaɪtnɪŋ/*
*Forms:  Also ME liȝtnynge, ME, 15 lyghtnyng, ME–15 lightnyng, lyght(e)nynge,* *lyt(e)nynge, (ME litynnynge, 15 lyghteling), 15–17 lightening, 16–17 light'ning.*

*Etymology:  Special use of lightening n.2; now differentiated in spelling.*

*1. The visible discharge of electricity between one group of clouds and another, or between the clouds and the ground. Also in particularized sense (now rare), A flash of lightning. like lightning, with the swiftness of lightning. Also in phr. †in less than, †to last no longer than a lightning .*

Note that the etymology is the same a *lightening*. So... we take a look at what [OED](http://ezproxy.bcu.ac.uk:2333/view/Entry/108232?rskey=09THkq&result=1#eid) has to say about *lightening*:

*lightening, n.2*

*Pronunciation:  /ˈlaɪt(ə)nɪŋ/*
*Forms:  See also lightning n.*
*Etymology:  < lighten v.2 + -ing suffix1.*

*a. The shedding or shining of light; suffusion with light, lighting up; fig. enlightenment, illumination.*

Here we see that *lightening* is again a noun, formed by adding the suffix -ing to the verb *lighten*.

In simple terms, Etymology Online and the Oxford English Dictionary both tell us that *lightning* is the -ing form of *lighten*. Adding an -ed suffix to a word that already has an -ing suffix is obvious nonsense.

The past form of lightning is formed by going back to the root *lighten* and adding an -ed suffix to get *lightened*

Staying with OED, if we search it for [lightninged](http://ezproxy.bcu.ac.uk:2333/view/Entry/108233?redirectedFrom=lightninged#eid), it has no entry. It returns only two quotations from early 20th century gazettes:

*1903   Westm. Gaz. 16 Nov. 8/2   The two metal balls..thundered and lightninged as they delivered the message.*

*1926   H. Caine in Strand Mag. Jan. 20/1   Mr. Gladstone leapt to his feet, whereupon the air of the House thundered and lightninged for a short ten minutes.*

This confirms the Ngram result that *lightninged* is not in widespread use.

Comment: This answers for lighten, not lightning.

Comment: Then why do they all say "*thundered* and lightened"? You think first it thundered, then they all ran outside and made something lighter?

Comment: @guifa: *lightning* was derived from the gerund form (*lightening*) of *lighten* in ME. So Roaring Fish's answer is apropos.

Comment: Thundered and lightninged is very much found: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thundered+and+lightninged&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthundered%20and%20lightninged%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Robusto regardless the source of the the word, it is now a verb in its own right, used more frequently for the meteorological sense than its original. It's like someone asking a question about enlighten and answering with lighten.

Comment: Guifa ~ can you give us the infinitive and progressive forms of this verb?

Comment: *the forecast said it was going to lightning today, and indeed it is lightning outside now*

Comment: @guifa ~ just to confirm... your suggestion is that *lightning* is a verb that has no -ing form?

Comment: @RoaringFish it has a present participle, but it is invariable from the bare form of the verb.

Comment: @guifa ~ I asked about -ing form, not present participle as that is only one of the three -ing forms none of which can be used with your *lightning* verb. Regardless of that, a present participle is, by definition, formed by verb + ing, but here you tell us it is invariant. That doesn't look very convincing at all given that you are insistant that the past form is not invariant but formed from verb + ed, so could you support it from a convincing source saying that *lightning* is a verb with an invariant present participle, and/or examples of other (action) verbs that are treated the same way?

Comment: @guifa ~ actually... don't bother looking. It will take too long so I will do it for you: - "lightning (n.)
late 13c., present participle of lightnen "make bright," extended form of Old English lihting, from leht (see light (n.))."  You see... *lightning* is *already* the -ing form, so your *lightninged* makes as much sense as 'swimminged' or 'cookinged'. The bare infinitive is *lighten*, hence the past participle of base verb + -ed is *lightened*.   Sources: -> http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lightning; http://illustratedetymology.com/Lightning

Comment: I frankly don't care what lightning's etymology is, you're committing an etymological fallacy. It is, today, a verb unto itself. You can deny that until you're blue in the face but that doesn't change reality. There is one verb with bare infinitive *lighten*, and there is another one that is *lightning*. I'm sorry that that is a difficult concept for you to grasp, and I'm sorry that the OED isn't a good enough source for you. For most people it is, and for most people, NGrams are sufficient enough to show use. Or do you deny that lightninged has shown up in published works?

Comment: Your own post claims that lightninged isn't found on Ngrams yet... surprise! It is.

Comment: @guifa ~ I checked the OED and is doesn't list *lightning* as a verb or *lightninged* as a past form. Can you provide a link to where you claim to have got this from?

Comment: @RoaringFish I have quoted the entry in my answer along with scholarly uses of the term.

Comment: @guifa... a couple of quotes is not OED listing *lighteninged* as a past form. As I said, there is no entry for *lightninged* and you a misleading people by saying there is.

Comment: Um, did you not read the first one that is *directly from the OED*?  But fine, I've screencapped the entry and included it in my answer.

Comment: I know the difference between quotes and a listing. Why don't you? What that is telling you is that the OED has two quotes including *lightninged* as a verb. That is *not* "the OED lists it" That would require an entry of its own which doesn't exist. To most of us, a word used twice in the past 100 years is not in widespread use. The verb actually listed, as in it has an entry and is not just a couple of quotes, is *lighten*.

Comment: @RoaringFish The picture I just posted **clearly** shows that it has its **own** entry. But *fine*, since that's not good enough for you, tomorrow when I get onto campus, I'll put up a print copy of it at the library and submit yet another piece of evidence of it having its *own* entry.  And if you're going to say it's used only twice in the past 100 years, what of the citations that I have provided?  Are you going to claim I'm misinterpreting them?

Comment: Learn what an OED entry is here -> http://www.oed.com/public/entrydisplay/the-entry-display

Comment: @RoaringFish right, you're just proving my point.  There is a unique and individual entry for *lightning, v.*.  Seriously, you're not even grasping at straws at this point.  You're just **wrong**.

Comment: Then explain why your pretence at a 'unique and individual entry for *lightning, v*' is completely different to what the OED says is an entry. The OED says an entry has an information panel with etymology, forms, meanings, citations, cross-references, etc. and you say they don't. I believe what the OED says is an entry...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18474/discussion-between-guifa-and-roaring-fish).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is dialectal because i couldn't find it anywhere but growing up I always heard 
It's lightninging for the present progressive tense and It lightninged for the past.

Comment: Yes Alex. I'm starting to think so as well - perhaps it varies upon the dialect. But from the *debate* between the folks on the other answers I think **lightninged** seems more acceptable. Again, its seems more like a dialect.

Comment: Which is your dialect? That's kinda cool that you have the double -ing.

Comment: I grew up in northern New York about an hour or so south of Montreal.

Answer (score 0):

In reading the above comments, I can't figure out how people come to their conclusions. The word 'lightening' and 'lightning' are two completely different words. You can use the root word 'lighten', but there is no root word for 'lightning'. That IS the word. Merriam Webster definitely has different definitions for each of the words.

Also, here is a more clear explanation: http://www.queens-english-society.com/lightning-vs-lightening